# Error al convertir de String a Int en TextBox

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp

Tengo un `GridView` y dentro de este tengo la function `RowUpdating` y al momento de querer cambiar los datos, me tira un error de conversión.

> Input string was not in a correct format.

En la manera que quiero convertir el `TextBox` es la siguiente:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtid")).Text);
```

un Tip que me da es el siguiente:

> When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to  taje the date berfore putting each Variable into the DateTime object.

pero obvio yo no quiero convertirlo a `DateTime` ya que es un `Id`.

Comment: Lo que está claro es que `((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtid")).Text` no te está devolviendo una cadena válida para convertira a Integer

Comment: y alguna idea del por que no lo esta hacienda?

Comment: ¿Estás intentando coger el valor de una celda del GridView?

Comment: si, desde el id, hasta los demas valores que la tabla en la BD traen el `TemplateField` del id, esta como `Visible:False` ya que es un valor que no quiero mostrar

Comment: Necesitas depurar tu código y ver que te está devolviendo exactamente `((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtid")).Text`

Comment: Puse el `Template` en `True` y si me trae el id, pero lo vuelvo a poner como `False` y ahi vuelve a fallar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el gridview puedes usar el `DataKeyNames`para definir las columnas a las cuales quieras acceder que esten ocultas y asi podras obtener el valor. puedes consultar mas informacion del DataKeyNames ---> [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda! en verdad ayudaron ;)